# NSMutableData's bytes to UnsafeMutableRawPointer not updating the value of mutableData

Tags: ios, swift3, icmp, unsafe-pointers, unsafemutablepointer

I am having a struct object. And a method, whose input is payload. Now I am creating a mutableData named `packet`, and it's mutable bytes are referring to ICMPHeader struct.

```
struct ICMPHeader {
    var type:UInt8
    var code:UInt8
    var checksum:UInt16
    var identifier:UInt16
    var sequenceNumber:UInt16
};


func createPacket(payload:NSData) -> NSData(){
    var packet:NSMutableData?
    var icmpPtr:ICMPHeader = ICMPHeader(type: 0, code: 0, checksum: 0, identifier: 0, sequenceNumber: 0)
    packet = NSMutableData(length: Int(MemoryLayout<ICMPHeader>.size + payload.length))

    if packet != nil {

       icmpPtr = packet!.mutableBytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: ICMPHeader.self).pointee

       icmpPtr.type = type
       icmpPtr.code = 0
       icmpPtr.checksum = 0
       icmpPtr.identifier = CFSwapInt16BigToHost(identifier)
       icmpPtr.sequenceNumber = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(identifier)
       memcpy(&icmpPtr + 1, payload.bytes, payload.length)

       if (requiresChecksum) {
           icmpPtr.checksum = in_cksum(packet!.bytes, bufferLen: packet!.length);
       }

   }
   return packet
}
```

Mutable bytes are successfully getting binded to struct, and values are also getting updated in struct `ICMPHeader`.

The issue is changing the values in struct is not changing the value of mutable data `packet`.

And if, I am trying to recreate the packet after creating struct, then it is crashing.

```
package = NSMutableData(bytes: unsafeBitCast(icmpPtr, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self), length: Int(MemoryLayout<ICMPHeader>.size + payload.length))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in XCode 8.1 Swift release notes.

After making the changes in struct object `icmpPtr` I have changed it back to buffer pointer.

```
var byteBuffer = [UInt8]()
withUnsafeBytes(of: &icmpPtr) {
    (bytes: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in byteBuffer += bytes
}
package.replaceBytes(in: NSMakeRange(0, byteBuffer.count), withBytes: byteBuffer)
```

So instead of creating the new Data object, I have replaced the bytes and it worked like a charm.

As per documentation:

> XCode 8.1 Release Notes:
>        https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html
>        Swift Section:
>
> A new withUnsafeBytes(of:) function exposes a value's in-memory
>   representation as an UnsafeRawBufferPointer. This example copies a
>   heterogenous struct into a homogeneous array of bytes:
>
> ```
> struct Header {
>  var x: Int
>  var y: Float
> }
>
> var header = Header(x: 0, y: 0.0)
> var byteBuffer = [UInt8]()
>
> withUnsafeBytes(of: &header) {
>     (bytes: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in byteBuffer += bytes
> }
> ```
>
> A new Array.withUnsafeBytes method exposes an array's underlying
>   buffer as an UnsafeRawBufferPointer. This example copies an array of
>   integers into an array of bytes:
>
> ```
> let intArray = [1, 2, 3]
> var byteBuffer = [UInt8]()
>
> intArray.withUnsafeBytes {
>     (bytes: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in byteBuffer += bytes
> }
> ```

So the final implementation is

```
struct ICMPHeader {
    var type:UInt8
    var code:UInt8
    var checksum:UInt16
    var identifier:UInt16
    var sequenceNumber:UInt16
};


func createPacket(payload:NSData) -> NSData(){
    var packet:NSMutableData?
    var icmpPtr:ICMPHeader = ICMPHeader(type: 0, code: 0, checksum: 0, identifier: 0, sequenceNumber: 0)
    packet = NSMutableData(length: Int(MemoryLayout<ICMPHeader>.size + payload.length))

    if packet != nil {

       icmpPtr = packet!.mutableBytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: ICMPHeader.self).pointee

       icmpPtr.type = type
       icmpPtr.code = 0
       icmpPtr.checksum = 0
       icmpPtr.identifier = CFSwapInt16BigToHost(identifier)
       icmpPtr.sequenceNumber = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(identifier)
       memcpy(&icmpPtr + 1, payload.bytes, payload.length)

       if (requiresChecksum) {
           icmpPtr.checksum = in_cksum(packet!.bytes, bufferLen: packet!.length);
       }

       var byteBuffer = [UInt8]()
       withUnsafeBytes(of: &icmpPtr) {
         (bytes: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in byteBuffer += bytes
       }
       packet.replaceBytes(in: NSMakeRange(0, byteBuffer.count), withBytes: byteBuffer)

   }
   return packet
}
```